# Changing time or offsetting it in OpenVZ contained server

Tags: linux, debian, time, openvz

I am trying to run a VPS, a Debian box contained in an OpenVZ container. Obviously, I cannot use `time --set` or any such command, as the time must be set via the parent node. The owner of the parent node, however refuses to adjust the time (which is 30 minutes slower than the actual time).

All the programs on my system, consequently, now recognized the false time and this throws a wrench in my syncing. Is there a way to possibly change the system time without interference from the container's administrator? Or perhaps, failing that, a way to make the programs "see" the time 30 minutes faster than what is reported by the container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do anything with the system time inside an OpenVZ container.

If the host refuses to fix the clock, go take your business elsewhere. They obviously don't want your money badly enough.

Comment: I see. Well, it was sort of a long shot anyway. Thanks. I just needed confirmation that I actually am doomed. I have LOTS of config and data on the server. Such a pain.

Comment: I would also suggest not using OpenVZ-based VPS at all. There are much better choices out there for most workloads.