# Why my server on Digital Ocean woke up with a wrong time?

Tags: ntp

Today one of my servers hosted on Digital Ocean (the only one hosted there) is reporting wrong time. It's two hours late.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
# then I set up the timezone to Europe/Rome

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Rome'
Local time is now:      Sat Jan 31 12:35:21 CET 2015.
Universal Time is now:  Sat Jan 31 11:35:21 UTC 2015.
```

But the time now is 10:35 in Rome and 9:35 UTC.

The command `date` is reporting the same time.
I tried updating the time with:

```
sudo ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com
# the same
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
# same again
```

By removing the `-s` flag I receive some errors:

```
sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov
31 Jan 14:11:49 ntpdate[18243]: sendto(time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov): Operation not permitted
31 Jan 14:11:51 ntpdate[18243]: sendto(time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov): Operation not permitted
31 Jan 14:11:53 ntpdate[18243]: sendto(time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov): Operation not permitted
31 Jan 14:11:55 ntpdate[18243]: sendto(time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov): Operation not permitted
31 Jan 14:11:57 ntpdate[18243]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

What else do I have to change in order to fix the problem ?

Comment: Drop the `-s` flag to `ntpdate`, for a start: we'd like to see the output, and forcibly sending it to syslog isn't the best way of doing that!  It may be, for example, that `ntpd` is running, in which case `ntpdate` won't fix the clock *and* `ntpd` won't fix it because you're running without `-g` and the clock's two hours wrong.  Only more output can help us isolate these issues!

Comment: Right, if I drop the `-s` flag I receive some errors. I have updated the post.

Comment: Is this a containerised server using OpenVZ?

Comment: It is a virtual server, but I do not know which technology is Digital Ocean using. I also opened a support there ticket but received no response yet.

Comment: If it's virtualised, my comments don't apply; but if it's merely containerised, see eg http://serverfault.com/questions/446289/changing-time-or-offsetting-it-in-openvz-contained-server - you usually can't set the clock inside a container.  Yet Another Reason why containers are *not* a cheap substitute for virtualisation, no matter how much the container sellers pretend that they are.

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a` and `mount`?

Comment: Probably I have found the issue: iptables was missing the rules for ntp. I disabled it temporary and it worked. Now I need to set the correct rules for the future. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you allowing 123/udp out through your firewall?

Comment: @MadHatter DigitalOcean are all KVM. No containers.

Comment: No. Is it just 123/UDP out? No in?